# When adding control variables to a regression, are we actually literally changing the comparisons being made in the data?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, econometrics, interpretation

If I am regressing wages on years of schooling, I can think of this as I am comparing the wages of people with different years of education. But now if I were to add the age of the individual as a control variable -- Is this literally now taking people in the data with the same age, and among those people, comparing the wages for different levels of education? Or is it by removing the correlation with age, making it 'as if' you are comparing these people with the same age, but mechanically it is not actually doing that?

I understand that with a fully saturated age variable (dummy variables for each age), it is doing something similar to that, but what if I included a continuous variable for age? Is the logic the same?

Comment: The FWL theorem helps with the intuition here. Nice animation here: https://x.com/ryxcommar/status/1571205569209409539?s=46&t=s4juvzZyqINFVm3po3wtWw

Comment: I found [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/what-does-it-mean-to-control-for-something-in-multiple-regression-744880620988) helpful.